# Laravel 5.2 with Sentinel 2 - Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-facade

In my base template of app.blade.php I do a simple check to see if the user is logged in. It looks like this:

```
@if (Sentinel::check())
    <li><a href="members.aspx">Members</a></li>
@else
    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
@endif
```

This triggers the `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting`. Any ideas why. I have the provider and facade defined properly in app.php. Like this:

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class,
    ....
],

'aliases' => [
    ....
    'Sentinel'  => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class,
    ....
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I can't say why you are getting this error, I can tell you how to fix it; you need to edit your `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in your `php.ini`.

Usually setting this to 200 or 300 does the trick, and is usually only an issue in local development where you are using xdebug.

You can set it like so; `xdebug.max_nesting_level=200` or `xdebug.max_nesting_level=300`.

More info on this setting can be found in the [docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level) for xdebug.

Comment: I'm not usually a fan of messing with those properties because I usually assume there's a bigger problem. However, that did appear to do the trick for this instance. Maybe it's just an inefficient function. Thanks.